# Enumerations : How to set value to the enumeration type class member?

Tags: c#-4.0, crm, enumeration, microsoft-dynamics

Below is the Enumeration defined.

```
 public enum MessageType
 {
   General = 1,
   Warning = 2,
   Update = 3,
   All = 4
  }
```

Class Message with the class member as Message Type :

```
 public class Message
 {

   public MessageType MessageType;

 }
```

Now, in below method I want to set Message Type from the CRM entity field value.

But I am not getting how to convert string to the enumeration type here.

```
public Message PopulateMessage(Entity entity)
{

  Message message = new Message();

  message.MessageType =  EntityExtension.ToString(entity,"as_message_type");

  return message;
}
```

Please suggest.

Thank you,
Mittal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Method or [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.enum.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Method of the Enum-Type to parse a string to a enum value.

```
message.MessageType = (MessageType) Enum.Parse(typeOf(MessageType), "as_message_type");
```

or

```
MessageType type;

bool parsed = Enum.TryParse<MessageType>("as_message_type", out type);

if (parsed) {
  message.MessageType = type;
}
```